# How best to use Interfaces/Generics for this Card/Deck example

Tags: c#, generics, interface, dependency-injection

I'm working on learning generics/using dependency injection/interfaces in order to have loosely coupled classes - however, I'm struggling.

For the below trivial card/deck example, how could I best adapt these classes (using the aforementioned techniques) so that I can pass any type of "Card/ICard" List in, for Deck to be able to populate/print said type. So for example, in Main, I want to be able to pass in List or List, and for deck to be able to handle this either way.

Deck.cs

```
public class Deck
{
    List<Card> cards;

    public Deck(List<Card> cards)
    {
        this.cards = cards;

        foreach (Card.Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.Suit))) {
            foreach (Card.Val value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.Val))) {
                cards.Add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
    }


    public void printDeck()
    {
        foreach(Card x in cards)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Card.cs

```
public class Card : ICard {
    Suit suit;
    Val value;

    public Card(Suit suit, Val value)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string formatCard = "Suit: " + suit + " Value: " + value;
        return formatCard;
    }

    public enum Suit
    {
        HEARTS = 1,
        SPADES = 2,
        CLUBS = 3,
        DIAMONDS = 4

    }

    public enum Val
    {
        ONE = 1,
        TWO = 2,
        THREE = 3,
        FOUR = 4,
        FIVE = 5
    }
}  
}
```

SpecialCard.cs

```
public class SpecialCard : ICard{
    Suit suit;
    Val val;

    public SpecialCard(Suit suit, Val val)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string formatCard = "Dragon: " + suit + " Value: " + val;
        return formatCard;
    }
    public enum Suit
    {
        RIDGEBACK = 1,
        FIREBALL = 2,
        SHORTSNOUT = 3,
        HORNTAIL = 4

    }

    public enum Val
    {
        UNO = 1,
        DOS = 2,
        TRES = 3,
        QUATTRO = 4,
        CINCZ = 5
    }
}   
}
```

ICard.cs

```
public interface ICard
{
    string ToString();
}
```

Main

```
static void Main()
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck(new List<Card>());
        deck.printDeck();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Thanks for any pointers!
FYP

Comment: ICard should ideally have Suit and Val properties because they define a contract (`ICard`) every card must adhere to. Also Suit and Val enums can be defined outside classes with all the constants merged (from Card and SpecialCard). Then you really don't need a SpecialCard type.

Comment: If I merge the constants, how will I be able to have different types of Card's (i.e. one that has normal Suits, and one that has Suits named after fictional dragons..) and be able to decide that in Main? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have the suit and value as enums as that makes it hard to substitute different implementations. In general I'd separate classes which hold state such as a card or a deck from classes which provide logic, such as a deck builder.

I don't think you need ToString() in ICard as all classes inherit System.Object, which implements ToString(). Anyway, I don't think the card should know its own long description. Why not let the client decide based on the information (suit, value) it has available.

Given that the implementation of both types of cards is the same I'd just have a single class with very little logic. Suit and value can just be a string for now as all you do is print the values. You may wish to change Value to be a class with an int value and string description if you need to compare strength of cards later.

```
public class Card
{
    public string Suit { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

your deck would then be a list of cards and the type of suit used and would delegate the building of itself elsewhere to avoid violating separation of concerns.

```
public class Deck
{
    public IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    public string SuitName { get; set; }
}
```

then the bulk of your logic would exist in the deck builder. To enable the client to know which deck to build I would create an enum.

```
public enum DeckType
{
    Standard,
    Special
}
```

and the builder would be (static as it holds no state)

```
public static class DeckBuilder
{
    public Deck Build(DeckType deckType)
    {
        var deck = new Deck();
        switch (deckType)
        {
            case DeckType.Standard:
                deck.SuitName = "Suit";
                deck.Cards = CreateStandardCards();
                break;
            case DeckType.Special:
                deck.SuitName = "Dragon";
                deck.Cards = CreateSpecialCards();
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("deckType");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Card> CreateStandardCards()
    {
        var suits = new List<string> { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"  };
        var values = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        return CreateCards(suits, values);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Card> CreateSpecialCards()
    {
        var suits = new List<string> { "Ridgeback", "Fireball", "Shortsnout", "Horntail"  };
        var values = new List<string> { "Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Quattro", "Cincz" };
        return CreateCards(suits, values);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Card> CreateCards(IEnumerable<string> suits, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        foreach (var suit in suits)
        foreach (var value in values)
            yield return new Card { Suit = suit, Value = value };
    }
}
```

an alternative to this approach would be to create an IDeckBuilder with different implementations for StandardDeckBuilder and SpecialDeckBuilder, meaning the enum isn't needed. I would do this if the switch statements became larger (i.e. if you added more properties which were dependant on the deck type).

The client needs to call the appropriate builder. I would also move the printDeck logic here. The deck class shouldn't know how to print. It shouldn't know that the output goes to console.

```
static void Main()
{
    var deck = DeckBuilder.Build(DeckType.Standard);
    foreach (var card in deck.Cards)
        Console.WriteLine(deck.SuitName + ": " + card.Suit + " Value: " + card.Value);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I haven't tried this so it may not compile - it's an illustration of the overall design I would use.